# Questions about Passive Voice in Present Tense

Tags: passive-voice

What would be the Active Voice for below sentences?

a) He is arrested by police.

b) A car is cleaned by him.

Also, Why past participle is used while constructing passive in present tense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) Police arrests him.

b) He cleans a car.

Comment: I think you are wrong. Passive voice of your sentences would be a) He was arrested by police and b) Car was cleaned by him. I have asked about present tense.

Comment: tricky stuff... :)  I corrected them - thanks for noticing